# How can I view all the messages I posted in a Slack channel?

Tags: slack

How to view all the messages, that I posted in a specific Slack channel?
I'm referring to the Slack website and not the Slack desktop program or phone application.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117406/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-how-can-i-view-all-the-messages-i-p).

Comment: [Why is this question on how to view all the messages one posted in a Slack channel kept closed?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5191/18147)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
from:me in:#random
```

... to list all messages I've posted in #random

[image: Screenshot from Slack]

Comment: What about a channel you're no longer a member of?  Or a private channel?  It won't show up in the auto-suggestions.

Comment: Or you can do just `from:me` and see everything you've posted in any channel, not just the ones you belong to...nice!

Comment: and, you can use `from:me during:today` to just find messages you posted today! Other date options that work are: `on:today` or `before:June` or `during:week` or `after:2014`