# Searching for all messages by user with Slack

Tags: search, slack

Using Slack I'm attempting to find all messages by user but following is returned :

[image]

I've tried search terms :

```
in:@username
```

and

```
all:@username
```

But same search result.

How to find all messages in all channels in all workspaces by username ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I view all the messages I posted in a Slack channel?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117076/how-can-i-view-all-the-messages-i-posted-in-a-slack-channel) : TLDR use <kbd> CTRL </kbd> + <kbd> K </kbd>  then type  `from:@user_name`

Comment: @pjmg thanks but this is not a duplicate as my requirement is to search for all messages in all channels in all workspaces for a given user - I do not want to have to specify the channel and workspace.

Comment: I agree that this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to find all messages by user by entering only `from:@username` into  the search box.